# How do I convert from long value to KB string format

Tags: c#, string, format

How do I represent a long value in KB like the snapshot picture?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably what you're looking for:

```
long memory = 210957130;
Console.WriteLine("{0:N0} K", memory / 1024);
Console.WriteLine(string.Format(new CultureInfo("en-US"), "{0:N0} K", memory / 1024));
```

If you'd like to use the thousand separator from your current regional settings, use the first option. If you specifically want to use a comma, use the second option.

Answer (score 9):

[From my blog](http://programanddesign.com/cs/human-readable-file-size-in-c-2/):

```
static string ReadableFileSize(double size, int unit=0)
{
    string[] units = { "B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB", "PB", "EB", "ZB", "YB" };

    while(size >= 1024) {
        size /= 1024;
        ++unit;
    }

    return String.Format("{0:0.#} {1}", size, units[unit]);
}
```

Although this doesn't do specifically what you asked. If you have a `long` which represents the number of `bytes`, then all you have to do is divide by 1024. 1 [KiB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kibibyte) = 1024 B.

---

I also wrote a [JavaScript version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14919494/65387) that's a bit more robust if anyone needs that.

Comment: i need to do it like the format in the picture .. your method changes the value to MB when it becomes >= Math.Pow(1024, 2) ..

Comment: @MurHafSoz: Yes, which is why I wrote the second paragraph. Simply divide by 1024. Unless you were questioning how you format a number with commas.... but Yuriy explained that anyway.