# setting up d3 axis with KiB, MiB, GiB units from values in bytes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a chart that is tracking file size. I want to set up an axis (Y) that displays file size with a proper Mebibyte suffix ex: KiB, MiB, GiB etc.

Now, I am feeding in data in bytes so theoretically a simple `.tickFormat()` method followed by a `d3.format()` should do the trick. Unfortunately that's not the case, since file size is actually multiples of 1024 (or 2^20) and not typical SI 10^6. What that means is that my line starts to plot but the axis is all weird.

Take for example a file size of 587108352 and if round that up to nearest MB i get 560MiB (using the 1024 (2^20) multiplier).

How can I setup my axis to work with that?

I tried this:

```
yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y)
     .tickFormat(function (d) {
     return d3.format(scope.formatOptions.specifier)(d * scope.formatOptions.multiplier) + scope.formatOptions.suffix;
     });
```

Where format options object is:

```
vm.FormatObjectSize = {
        specifier: ".0s", // decimal notation with an SI prefix, rounded to significant digits.
        multiplier: 1, // none
        suffix: "b" // bytes
    };
```

That doesn't exactly work too well:

[image]

Comment: the Sugar.js library has a method to generalize the number to a string for you: https://sugarjs.com/docs/#/Number/bytes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tickFormat` with a function to convert the file size. Here, I'm using the function provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14919494/5768908), which I named `fileSize`.

So, your `tickFormat` should be:

```
.tickFormat(function(d){
    return fileSize(d)
 }
```

Here is a demo, going from `0` to `587108352`:

```js
var scale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .domain([0, 587108352])
  .range([20, 470]);

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var gX = svg.append("g").attr("transform", "translate(0,50)")
  .call(d3.axisBottom(scale).tickValues(scale.ticks(5).concat(scale.domain())).tickFormat(function(d) {
    return fileSize(d)
  }))

function fileSize(bytes) {
  var thresh = 1024;
  if (Math.abs(bytes) < thresh) {
    return bytes + ' B';
  }
  var units = ['KiB', 'MiB', 'GiB', 'TiB', 'PiB', 'EiB', 'ZiB', 'YiB'];
  var u = -1;
  do {
    bytes /= thresh;
    ++u;
  } while (Math.abs(bytes) >= thresh && u < units.length - 1);
  return bytes.toFixed(1) + ' ' + units[u];
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<svg width="500" height="100"></svg>
```

As you can see, the last value for `587108352` is 559.9 Mebibytes, which is the correct value.

By the way, your question's title is a bit incorrect: what you want is actually **KiB, MiB, GiB** etc, not Kb, Mb, Gb...

Also, a file/storage size can be provided using either MB/GB/TB/etc or MiB/GiB/TiB/etc, it depends on the case. For instance, HD manufacturers normally use decimal (1000), while RAM manufacturers normally use 1024.

Comment: As always amazing answer and a great explanation. Thank you!