# highcharts round generated y labels in 1024 multiply not 1000

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I have a chart with sample `data: [1462218035, 2079623792, 2146097338, 2169087177]` and in y axis label i convert it to human readable bytes:

```
yAxis: {
    labels: {
    useHTML: true,
    formatter: function () {
        return bytesToReadable(this.value, true);
    },
  },
}
```

**bytesToReadable** converts bytes to human readable data: `1,36 GB - 1,94 GB - 2 GB` and it shows y labels like: `953,67 MB - 1,86 GB - 2,79 GB` those are `2,000,000,000 - 4,000,000,000 - 6,000,000,000` converted by bytesToReadable. What i want is `2,000,000,000 - 4,000,000,000 - 6,000,000,000` generated by highcharts to be multiply of 1024 to be correct numbers after convert like `100 MB - 1GB - 4GB`.

Comment: can you try to clarify what you want? For example given data: `2,000,000,000 - 4,000,000,000 - 6,000,000,000` what is given/displayed by highcharts vs what you want to see?

Comment: @depperm It displays ```953,67 MB - 1,86 GB - 2,79 GB``` in labels, i want ```100 MB - 1GB - 4GB```

Comment: how do you go from 953,67MB to 100MB? Do you mean 1 GB? why does 1.86GB go to 1GB but 2.76GB goes to 4GB? that is what I don't understand

Comment: @depperm No it's just a sample, I just want that numbers to be rounded numbers without decimals.

Comment: so show us the code of bytesToReadable and see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14919494/3462319)

Comment: @depperm My bytesToReadable works correctly i dont want to round numbers in this function because decimals are important for me, I want yAxis lables defualt to be multiply of 1024 that when i convert by bytesToReadable it gives me correct numbers.

Comment: Hi @Fateme Fazli, Please try to use `tickInterval` property. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4806/

Comment: @ppotaczek It helped me so much thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tickInterval` property:

```
yAxis: {
  tickInterval: 1024
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/6m4e8x0y/4806/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/gantt/yAxis.tickInterval