# toFixed() dynamically in js

Tags: javascript

```
let a = 2.0123456789;
let b = 10;
let c = 7.000123456;
let d = 4.10002345;
a.toFixed(2); // "2.01"  // It's fine.
b.toFixed(2); // "10.00" // It should be "10"
c.toFixed(2); // "7.00"  // It should be "7"
d.toFixed(2); // "4.10"  // It should be "4.1"
```

I have no idea how do I cut the number dynamically.

Comment: What do you mean "dynamically?" Just pass to `toFixed()` any expression representing the number of digits you want.

Comment: `if(a % 1 === 0){ console.log(a.toFixed(0))}else{console.log(a.toFixed(2))}
`

Comment: @Ifaruki, I think if you divide something by one. This rest will always be 0 :p Your code makes no sense

Comment: @Wimanicesir well `console.log(2.01 % 1 === 0)` outputs false while `console.log(2 % 1 === 0)` outputs true

Comment: Oh, in that case 2.10 will always give false and will not be correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you convert it to number, this will happen automatically.

```js
let a = 2.0123456789;
let b = 10;
let c = 7.000123456;
let d = 4.10002345;

console.log(Number(a.toFixed(2)));
console.log(Number(b.toFixed(2)));
console.log(Number(c.toFixed(2)));
console.log(Number(d.toFixed(2)));
```