# Revert file size in human-readable string to bytes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, file

I didn't see any example of reverting human-readable file size to an integer

There're a lot of functions which help to convert file size to human readble, such as:
1024 bytes -> 1KB. Here is an question about this: [Converting file size in bytes to human-readable string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420352/converting-file-size-in-bytes-to-human-readable-string)

But I didn't see anywhere to support revert the process, such as: 1Kb -> 1024.

I recieved data from backend API, and it returns, for example `10MB`, and I want to convert this String to an integer (bytes) to compare file sizes of multiple files. How to I do this in Javascript?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: It’s just base math. n KB = n * 1024 B, n MB = n * 1024 * 1024 B. You might want to round result to integer. What specific difficulty did you encounter and couldn’t overcome?

Comment: Avoid it if you can. Just store original size somewhere and than use it when needed. Otherwise split number and unit and multiply that number by value of the unit. B = 1, kB =  1024 and so on...