# KB to MB/KB Conversion in JavaScript/TypeScript

Tags: javascript

I have a data that has returns values of KB always.
Just wondering if this conversion is correct? Should it be 1024 instead of 1000?

It should display KB if its appropriate to show KB else show MB already when its appropriate to show in MB.

```
  const fileSizeFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", {
   minimumFractionDigits: 1,
  });

  if (fileSize > 1000) {
    convertedFileSize = `${fileSizeFormat.format(fileSize / 1000)} MB`;
  } else {
    convertedFileSize = `${fileSizeFormat.format(fileSize)} KB`;
  }
```

Comment: Why do you ask this question? Do you have a reason to think the code is wrong? Do you want an answer like: _"Yes, the code is correct"_? Write unit tests instead of asking.

Comment: No, it shouldn't be 1024 instead of 1000. 1 MB = 1000 KB and 1 MiB = 1024 KiB.

Comment: @jabaa 1024 bytes = 1kb, 1024kb = 1mb, 1024mb = 1gb, 1024 gb = 1tb

Comment: this is a common question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420352/converting-file-size-in-bytes-to-human-readable-string, also I prefer to use multiples of 1000 since its easier than trying to convert larger values of multiples of 1024, for instance 1.24MB is obvious, 1.24MiB is not so obvious

Comment: No, k is Kilo (1000), m is Mega (1000000) and so on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting file size in bytes to human-readable string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420352/converting-file-size-in-bytes-to-human-readable-string)

Answer (score 1):

If you're assuming names litterally then your code is right:

1 kB = 1000 bytes

1 KiB = 1024 bytes

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen you're wrong. This answer is correct. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilobyte

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen A kibibyte is kib. A kilobyte is kb

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen In that case you all made it wrong. It's standardized. And it can have legal consequences

Comment: Try to ask a lawyer if you interchange it.

Comment: correct, but i'll also work in kibibytes, as base 2 is more sensable in computer science

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Yes, but the question is about kilobyte (KB), not kibibyte(KiB)

Comment: interesting enough when buying prepaid data from Vodacom, a 1GB data bundle, gives 1024Mbs to use. so explain that please, and they are a large company.

Comment: @DeanVanGreunen Yes, people make mistakes. Companies aren't perfect. I've already sued Samsung and I've won. Such things happen. Just because some large companies make some mistakes, it doesn't mean, this is correct.

Comment: even with standards, people f up